# Add zone to cloudflare with API

Tags: api, cloudflare

I'm trying to add all my domains to cloudflare through the API (https://api.cloudflare.com,  i'm using this lib: https://github.com/jamesryanbell/cloudflare)

Adding a zone works, but once added, I need to login to the cloudflare website to complete the setup wizard (I jump-start the domain, so cloudflare scans for dns-records).

I really would like to complete the wizard through the API (adding 1000+ domains manually is a bit tedious), but I cannot find in the API how to do it.  What I did find, is an error code "Could not promote zone to step 3", and I suspect step 3 is the next step in the wizard. So i'm guessing it should be possible.

Does someone had the need to do the same thing and succeeded? Alle help is greatly appreciated.

PS: I already e-mailed cloudflare support, but with no response so far.